# cannot display image in Yii

Tags: image, view, yii

I'm trying to display image in CDetailView, this is my code :

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
            'image',
                    array(
                    'name'=>'image',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=> CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'../../../images/arsip/'.$model->image),
                    ),

            ),
    ));
?>
```

the page can view, but the image cannot display, I'm also trying with `'value'=>html_entity_decode(CHtml::image($model->image,'alt',array('width'=>341,'height'=>232))),` but only display the 'alt' string.

Comment: check your path. It should be something like `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/".$model->image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Observer the image path in mozilla firebug.

I hope this is your folder Structure

```
        App
        |
        |
        ----assets
        |
        |
        ----css
        |
        |
        ----images
        |   |
        |   |
        |   ---------arsip
        |
        ----protected
        |
        |
        ----themes
```

If this is.. Change the path like below.

```
       CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/arsip/'..$model->image),
```