# How to add width tag in CDetailView to display image in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I can show image in the details view reading this [cannot display image in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803330/cannot-display-image-in-yii) topic. I want to add width and alt tag into img tag. Is it possible?

I wrote as follows:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'table table-striped responsive-table'),
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'code',
        'name',
        'description',
        array(
            'type'=>'raw',
            'width'=>'200',
            'alt'=>'hi images',
            'value'=> CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/products/'.$model->image),
        ),
        'price',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all sorts of html options as it is [described here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail).

public static string image(string $src, string $alt='', array **$htmlOptions**=array ( ))

so it would be like

```
CHtml::image(
    Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/products/' . $model->image ,
    'some thing here' , array(
    'style' => 'width = 200px; height: 100px',
));
```